# How to copy ntfs/windows data from external usb hd to ubuntu ext4 disk?

Tags: 16.04, external-hdd, ext4, copy

I'm looking for a solution to transfer my data from my notebook (a windows 10 laptop) to my new desktop with ubuntu 16.04 using my external Hdd.

I did a copy from laptop >> Hdd, but now I can't copy from hdd>>ubutu ext4 disk.

It's show a message of error.

Any tips?

Comment: I can't see any reason why you'd not succeed, so I'd suggest pasting (your command plus) the whole error message to your question so we can see what you did wrong, or how to resolve your issue.  (*please don't provide it in a comment; past to your question*)

Comment: @guiverc it was a stupid problem, was only about permissions to write (I had only read permissions). I change it using "sudo chown user path".
Anyway THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you copied files from your Win10 laptop onto an external HDD. I'm assuming that your external HDD is in some sort of USB connected enclosure. It would probably be helpful to know the file system format of the external HDD, but I am going to assume it is NTFS.

If this is all true then you should be able to simply plug your external HDD into your Ubuntu 16.04 desktop. Ubuntu 16.04 should be pre-installed with the necessary ntfs-3g components to read your NTFS HDD. Then you should be able to simply copy the files from the external HDD to your Ubuntu 16.04 desktop using either a drag and drop method or possibly something like rsync.

Hopefully that helps!

Some links that might help:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions
[https://help.ubuntu.com/community/rsync](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/rsync%20rsync)

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem as a permission to write into the raid1 array.

It was simple to change using

```
  sudo chown username pathToArray
```